# Convert python long/int to fixed size byte array

Tags: python, arrays, long-integer, diffie-hellman, rc4-cipher

I'm trying to implement RC4 and DH key exchange in python. Problem is that I have no idea about how to convert the python long/int from the key exchange to the byte array I need for the RC4 implementation. Is there a simple way to convert a long to the required length byte array?

**Update**: forgot to mention that the numbers I'm dealing with are 768 bit unsigned integers.

Comment: not sure if it'll help but check the `struct` module: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I haven't done any benchmarks, but this recipe "works for me".

The short version: use `'%x' % val`, then `unhexlify` the result. The devil is in the details, though, as `unhexlify` requires an even number of hex digits, which `%x` doesn't guarantee. See the docstring, and the liberal inline comments for details.

```py
from binascii import unhexlify

def long_to_bytes (val, endianness='big'):
    """
    Use :ref:`string formatting` and :func:`~binascii.unhexlify` to
    convert ``val``, a :func:`long`, to a byte :func:`str`.

    :param long val: The value to pack

    :param str endianness: The endianness of the result. ``'big'`` for
      big-endian, ``'little'`` for little-endian.

    If you want byte- and word-ordering to differ, you're on your own.

    Using :ref:`string formatting` lets us use Python's C innards.
    """

    # one (1) hex digit per four (4) bits
    width = val.bit_length()

    # unhexlify wants an even multiple of eight (8) bits, but we don't
    # want more digits than we need (hence the ternary-ish 'or')
    width += 8 - ((width % 8) or 8)

    # format width specifier: four (4) bits per hex digit
    fmt = '%%0%dx' % (width // 4)

    # prepend zero (0) to the width, to zero-pad the output
    s = unhexlify(fmt % val)

    if endianness == 'little':
        # see http://stackoverflow.com/a/931095/309233
        s = s[::-1]

    return s
```

...and my [nosetest](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) unit tests ;-)

```py
class TestHelpers (object):
    def test_long_to_bytes_big_endian_small_even (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0x42)
        assert s == '\x42'

        s = long_to_bytes(0xFF)
        assert s == '\xff'

    def test_long_to_bytes_big_endian_small_odd (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0x1FF)
        assert s == '\x01\xff'

        s = long_to_bytes(0x201FF)
        assert s == '\x02\x01\xff'

    def test_long_to_bytes_big_endian_large_even (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0xab23456c8901234567)
        assert s == '\xab\x23\x45\x6c\x89\x01\x23\x45\x67'

    def test_long_to_bytes_big_endian_large_odd (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0x12345678901234567)
        assert s == '\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\x01\x23\x45\x67'

    def test_long_to_bytes_little_endian_small_even (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0x42, 'little')
        assert s == '\x42'

        s = long_to_bytes(0xFF, 'little')
        assert s == '\xff'

    def test_long_to_bytes_little_endian_small_odd (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0x1FF, 'little')
        assert s == '\xff\x01'

        s = long_to_bytes(0x201FF, 'little')
        assert s == '\xff\x01\x02'

    def test_long_to_bytes_little_endian_large_even (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0xab23456c8901234567, 'little')
        assert s == '\x67\x45\x23\x01\x89\x6c\x45\x23\xab'

    def test_long_to_bytes_little_endian_large_odd (self):
        s = long_to_bytes(0x12345678901234567, 'little')
        assert s == '\x67\x45\x23\x01\x89\x67\x45\x23\x01'
```

Comment: I encountered problems when the value is 0 (Python 3.5) ```binascii.Error: Odd-length string```, quick fix for this: replace ```s = unhexlify(fmt % val)``` with ```s = unhexlify('00') if fmt % val == '0' else unhexlify(fmt % val)```

Comment: This is more concise. https://pastebin.com/iQRXyxsM

Answer (score 65):

With Python 3.2 and later, you can use `int.to_bytes` and `int.from_bytes`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

Comment: It OverflowError's out on big numbers.

Answer (score 32):

Everyone has overcomplicated this answer:

```
some_int = <256 bit integer>
some_bytes = some_int.to_bytes(32, sys.byteorder)
my_bytearray = bytearray(some_bytes)
```

You just need to know the number of bytes that you are trying to convert. In my use cases, normally I only use this large of numbers for crypto, and at that point I have to worry about modulus and what-not, so I don't think this is a big problem to be required to know the max number of bytes to return.

Since you are doing it as 768-bit math, then instead of 32 as the argument it would be 96.

Comment: In Python 3 this solution worked really well for 2048 bit integer. It Python 2.7 it works only for int (2048 bit integer is long in Python 2.7).

Comment: In Python 2.7 `some_bytes = some_int.to_bytes(32, sys.byteorder)` produces error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'` 

Comment: Not quite everyone... see the answer by @JackOConnor

Answer (score 13):

One-liner:

```
bytearray.fromhex('{:0192x}'.format(big_int))
```

The 192 is 768 / 4, because OP wanted 768-bit numbers and there are 4 bits in a hex digit. If you need a bigger `bytearray` use a format string with a higher number. Example:

```
>>> big_int = 911085911092802609795174074963333909087482261102921406113936886764014693975052768158290106460018649707059449553895568111944093294751504971131180816868149233377773327312327573120920667381269572962606994373889233844814776702037586419
>>> bytearray.fromhex('{:0192x}'.format(big_int))
bytearray(b'\x96;h^\xdbJ\x8f3obL\x9c\xc2\xb0-\x9e\xa4Sj-\xf6i\xc1\x9e\x97\x94\x85M\x1d\x93\x10\\\x81\xc2\x89\xcd\xe0a\xc0D\x81v\xdf\xed\xa9\xc1\x83p\xdbU\xf1\xd0\xfeR)\xce\x07\xdepM\x88\xcc\x7fv\\\x1c\x8di\x87N\x00\x8d\xa8\xbd[<\xdf\xaf\x13z:H\xed\xc2)\xa4\x1e\x0f\xa7\x92\xa7\xc6\x16\x86\xf1\xf3')
>>> lepi_int = 0x963b685edb4a8f336f624c9cc2b02d9ea4536a2df669c19e9794854d1d93105c81c289cde061c0448176dfeda9c18370db55f1d0fe5229ce07de704d88cc7f765c1c8d69874e008da8bd5b3cdfaf137a3a48edc229a41e0fa792a7c61686f1f
>>> bytearray.fromhex('{:0192x}'.format(lepi_int))
bytearray(b'\tc\xb6\x85\xed\xb4\xa8\xf36\xf6$\xc9\xcc+\x02\xd9\xeaE6\xa2\xdff\x9c\x19\xe9yHT\xd1\xd91\x05\xc8\x1c(\x9c\xde\x06\x1c\x04H\x17m\xfe\xda\x9c\x187\r\xb5_\x1d\x0f\xe5"\x9c\xe0}\xe7\x04\xd8\x8c\xc7\xf7e\xc1\xc8\xd6\x98t\xe0\x08\xda\x8b\xd5\xb3\xcd\xfa\xf17\xa3\xa4\x8e\xdc"\x9aA\xe0\xfay*|aho\x1f')
```

[My answer had used `hex()` before. I corrected it with `format()` in order to handle ints with odd-sized byte expressions. This fixes previous complaints about `ValueError`.]

Comment: it does not work if you don't produce a Long though. I think smt like 
bytearray.fromhex(hex(2**61-1).strip('0x').strip('L')) is safer

Comment: @MarioAlemi the code in your comment is wrong. `strip('0x')` will also strip the trailing zeros, which will result bad result (and sometimes `ValueError`)!

Comment: @Jess Austin: Your solution is totally wrong, because it works only when x consists of even number of hex-digits.

Example:
`x=0x963b685edb4a8f336f624c9cc2b02d9ea4536a2df669c19e9794854d1d93105c81c289cde061c0448176dfeda9c18370db55f1d0fe5229ce07de704d88cc7f765c1c8d69874e008da8bd5b3cdfaf137a3a48edc229a41e0fa792a7c61686f1fL`

Comment: @lepi can you make an example?

Comment: @MarioAlemi bytearray.fromhex(hex(0x11000000).strip('0x').strip('L')) 
It won't just strip the '0x' character sequence from the beginning, it will remove **all** the '0' and **all** the 'x' characters from **both** side. When the number is not a Long and has tailing zeros, those will be also removed.

Comment: @lepi thanks, I learned smt about strip() I did not know! Smt like that should work for the example, not sure there are other cases...
    bytearray.fromhex(hex(0x11000000).lstrip('0x').strip('L'))

Comment: This is a good solution for Python 2. It is important to have an even number of characters (like the 192 in the example), or a ValueError is raised. (It was mentioned before as a problem with the previous solution, but it is still something to watch out for).

Comment: @Justin the current solution still works no matter what the size of the argument to `format()`, so long as it fits in the space specified by the format expression string. That wasn't the case with the previous solution. `fromhex()` can't handle weird expressions so the format expression string should not be weird. One wouldn't expect that string would ever be dynamic, so that should be fine.

Comment: Right, I was just trying to point out that if you change the 192 in the format string to 191 (or to any odd number), you will get a ValueError. Just something that tripped me up.

Answer (score 8):

*long/int to the byte array* looks like exact purpose of `struct.pack`.  For long integers that exceed 4(8) bytes, you can come up with something like the next:

```
>>> limit = 256*256*256*256 - 1
>>> i = 1234567890987654321
>>> parts = []
>>> while i:
        parts.append(i & limit)
        i >>= 32

>>> struct.pack('>' + 'L'*len(parts), *parts )
'\xb1l\x1c\xb1\x11"\x10\xf4'

>>> struct.unpack('>LL', '\xb1l\x1c\xb1\x11"\x10\xf4')
(2976652465L, 287445236)
>>> (287445236L << 32) + 2976652465L
1234567890987654321L
```

Comment: But it won't help with big numbers (> 8 bytes), which will usually be used for cryptographic applications.

Comment: it's written not to be generic but more like fixed size solution to common problem of representing all possible ip's or similar...

Answer (score 7):

You can try using [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters):

```
import struct
struct.pack('L',longvalue)
```

Comment: Sadly no, error: integer out of range for 'L' format code. It's a 768 bit long, which is quite a bit bigger than the 4 byte unsigned int.

Comment: Downvoted because Python long int are arbitrarily long integers. Think of it like an array of 32 (or whatever) bits integers. A C long is a size defined datatype. With this response, you are confusing both.

Answer (score 7):

Little-endian, reverse the result or the range if you want Big-endian:

```
def int_to_bytes(val, num_bytes):
    return [(val & (0xff << pos*8)) >> pos*8 for pos in range(num_bytes)]
```

Big-endian:

```
def int_to_bytes(val, num_bytes):
    return [(val & (0xff << pos*8)) >> pos*8 for pos in reversed(range(num_bytes))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you need to do is convert the int/long into its base 256 representation -- i.e. a number whose "digits" range from 0-255. Here's a fairly efficient way to do something like that:

```
def base256_encode(n, minwidth=0): # int/long to byte array
    if n > 0:
        arr = []
        while n:
            n, rem = divmod(n, 256)
            arr.append(rem)
        b = bytearray(reversed(arr))
    elif n == 0:
        b = bytearray(b'\x00')
    else:
        raise ValueError

    if minwidth > 0 and len(b) < minwidth: # zero padding needed?
        b = (minwidth-len(b)) * '\x00' + b
    return b
```

You many not need the`reversed()`call depending on the endian-ness desired (doing so would require the padding to be done differently as well). Also note that as written it doesn't handle negative numbers.

You might also want to take a look at the similar but highly optimized `long_to_bytes()` function in the`number.py`module which is part of the open source [Python Cryptography Toolkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto). It actually converts the number into a string, not a byte array, but that's a minor issue.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 does not implement the int.to- very slow_bytes() method.

I tried 3 methods:

1. hex unpack/pack : very slow
2. byte shifting 8 bits at a time: significantly faster.
3. using a "C" module and packing into the lower (7 ia64 or 3 i32) bytes.
   This was about twice as fast as 2/ . It is the fastest option, but still too slow.

All these methods are very inefficient for two reasons:

- Python 2.7 does not support this useful operation.
- c does not support extended precision arithmetic using the carry/borrow/overflow flags available on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0x12345678
s = struct.pack('<I',i)
b = struct.unpack('BBBB',s)
```