# I need help converting a piece of Java into python

Tags: java, python, serial-port, arduino-uno

Following Java code creates a message I can write to an arduino serial port to control a robotic arm:

```
public static byte[] uArmMessage(short armRot, short armStr, short armHt, short handAng, boolean ctlData){
   byte[] msg ={(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xAA,(byte)((armRot>>8) 0xFF),
      (byte)(armRot&0xFF),(byte)((armStr>>8)&0xFF),
      (byte)(armStr&0xFF),(byte)((armHt>>8)&0xFF),
      (byte)(armHt&0xFF),(byte)((handAng>>8)&0xFF),
      (byte)(handAng&0xFF),(byte)(ctlData ? 1 : 2)};
   return msg;
}
```

I need help writing this function in python. If someone could explain to me how exactly i get the output from this function into an arduino I would also really appreciate it!

if it is any help I have a [PDF](http://evol.net/go/communication_protocol) that explains the Communication Protocol being used.

if this is not the place for this kind of question, could someone reefer me to somewhere more fitting?

Comment: Doesn't look simple to me. And SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: You should have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730927/convert-python-long-int-to-fixed-size-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
msg =[0xFF,0xAA,((armRot>>8)& 0xFF),
      (armRot&0xFF),((armStr>>8)&0xFF),
      (armStr&0xFF),((armHt>>8)&0xFF),
      (armHt&0xFF),((handAng>>8)&0xFF),
      (handAng&0xFF),(1 if ctlData else 2)];

s = serial.Serial("COM5",9600)
s.write("".join(map(chr,msg)))
```

basically it was just a matter of remove all the `(Byte)` and replaceing `{}` with `[]` ....