# Converting int to bytes

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I would like to convert long into bytes in Python 3.

Following code I'm using in C#:

```
long time = 7620584977
var a = BitConverter.GetBytes(time).Reverse().ToArray()
// a is [0,0,0,1,198,56,230,224]
```

Is there a similar simple code in Python (3)?

Comment: Did you even look ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730927/convert-python-long-int-to-fixed-size-byte-array

Comment: no i did see it. Thank you for reply